# How much RAM can my laptop really support?

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire, ddr3

I have an Acer Aspire E1-571-6837 laptop and I've read on different sources that the maximum memory it can handle is 8GB of DDR3 (2x4GB, 4GB per slot), but I read [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/72056/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-BGA) that the max memory the CPU can withstand is 32GB.

Now I'd like to know for sure what's the true max memory for said laptop, of course, depending on my system specs. But ok, the main question is, can the laptop handle 16GB (2x8GB) of PC3-12800 DDR3 memory? Or can it only withstand 8GB? (2x4GB)

The system specs are the following:

- Motherboard: Acer EA50 HC CR with one of two memory slots available. One of the slots reads "DDR3", so I'm guessing it can only take that memory type. It also reads on the slot "1.5V" so I'm guessing too that's the max voltage it can handle.
- CPU: Intel Core i5-3230M @2.60GHz with turbo boost up to 3.2GHz
- RAM/memory: Currently it has 1x4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 memory module with a max frequency of approximately 800MHz in one of the slots. The brand of the memory module is Hynix (I read it's owned by Hyundai Electronics).
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000 with up to 1824 MB (1.8GB) of graphics memory (that's the max graphics memory with dynamic/shared video memory included)
- OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit

One more question: The motherboard has a total amount of memory it can support right? So, even if the CPU can handle 32GB of memory, that doesn't mean the motherboard can handle 32GB as well right?

Comment: very briefly crucial.com

Comment: This question can be summed up as: I don't like what the manual is telling me the limits are.

Answer (score 4):

> The motherboard has a total amount of memory it can support right? So, even if the CPU can handle 32gigs of memory, that doesn't mean the motherboard can handle 32gigs as well right?

You are correct, just because the CPU can support it, doesn't mean the motherboard/chipset can.

> I have an Acer Aspire E1-571-6837 laptop, & I've read on different sources that the max memory it can handle is 8GB of DDR3

You read properly.  Acer, [Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search?DeviceType=3&Mfr=ACE&Line=Aspire&Model=78151), and [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-e1-571-6837) all say the same thing: 2 slots, 8GB max. Feel free to try a couple 8GB sticks in there, they probably won't work, but it won't damage anything by trying them.

If it does work, then bonus! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have an Acer E1-571 with a i5-2450m, I've checked out a few websites that say that this computer can only handle 8 GB, which is not true.

I successfully installed 2x8GB DDR3L 1600 Mhz and it works like a charm.
I also replace the wifi card, the original was a broadcom crap, now I have a atheros 9280 natively supported by OS X (recognized as Airport Extreme), the range and stability of this new wifi card is outstanding.
I really love this computer, I have Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan installed on it, and it works flawlessly

I might try to upgrade the cpu to an Ivy Bridge soon to see if it can handle (it is the same socket)

Peace

System memory report:

Logements mémoire :

ECC : Désactivées
  Mémoire pouvant être mise à niveau :  Oui

BANK0/DIMM0 :

Taille :  8 Go
  Type :    DDR3
  Vitesse : 1600 MHz
  État :    OK
  Fabricant :   Crucial Technology
  Numéro de pièce : CT102464BF160B.M16FP
  Numéro de série : -

BANK1/DIMM0 :

Taille :  8 Go
  Type :    DDR3
  Vitesse : 1600 MHz
  État :    OK
  Fabricant :   Crucial Technology
  Numéro de pièce : CT102464BF160B.M16FP
  Numéro de série : -

[image: about this 'mac']

Comment: Ack! Somehow a flag for another answer got attached to this one - please disregard any notifications along those lines - this is actually good :)

Comment: Hi sorry for the necromancy, but did you go through with that cpu upgrade? How did it go? What cpu did you use? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

try Everest benchmark. tell you wat is wat  and every thing from softwares /bois /speeds run by device eg cpu fsb ram fsb, os running/environments / chipset and vendors and its benchmarks an limitations . not just wat u want to install vendors. and manufacturers. have bit just hardware perks but software too if u install generic on oem u can lose your licencse to use it and perks that was factory-installed if then reinstalled the original softwares are unsigned if system depends on it like 64 bit.downgrades to 32 losing abilty to use miee than. 4gig ram